# Why is the File im opening not found because the File is there

Tags: java, filenotfoundexception

I read in a file selected by a JFileChooser, which means that the file exists and I know it's there, but I still get a FileNotFoundException.

I hard-coded the path to this file and that works fine.

```java
JFileChooser chooser = new JFileChooser();
int rueckgabeWert = chooser.showOpenDialog(null);

if (rueckgabeWert == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION)
{
  filetoopen = chooser.getSelectedFile().getName();
  Path path = Paths.get(filetoopen);
  List<String> allLines = null;
  try
  {
    allLines = Files.readAllLines(path, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
  }
  catch (IOException e1)
  {
    e1.printStackTrace();
  }

  for (int i = 0; i < allLines.size(); i++)
  {
    System.out.println(allLines.get(i));
  }

}
```

How can I get the file to open the file correctly?

Comment: Gonna go out on a limb and say you probably don't wanna call `getName()`, you're probably losing the full path.

Comment: You probably could have solved this yourself by printing out the value of `filetoopen`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

¿What is `filetoopen`, is it an file? By the line `chooser.getSelectedFile().getName()` you are only telling the `JFileChooser` to just get the name of the file, you should try with `getAbsolutePath()` instead of `getName()`. And also change `chooser.showOpenDialog(null);` by `chooser.showOpenDialog(chooser);`. I hope it helps you.

Comment: Looks like a string

Answer (score 2):

`chooser.getSelectedFile().getName()` returns the name of the file.  You need to get the complete path to the file to be able to open it.

Use `chooser.getSelectedFile().getAbsolutePath()` instead.

Answer (score 2):

As already stated, `getName()` returns the name of the file, not the path.
If you want to open the file via a `Path`, you can use the `toPath()` function of `File`:

```java
...
File filetoopen = chooser.getSelectedFile();
List<String> allLines = null;
try {
    allLines = Files.readAllLines(filetoopen.toPath(), StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
} catch (IOException e1) {                          
    e1.printStackTrace();
}
...
```